# Eclipse juno startup error, after upgrading adt 21.0 to 22.0

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, startup

I'm new for android development kit, I was install new software from  http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/, while downloading a receiver an warning message stated like "if i proceed further the product may go vulnerable" i pressed ok after that my eclipse have been restarted. while doing this process i got startup error states "An error has occured. see the log file follow by my adt installation path".

please help me to get rid of this..

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be an error occurred while downloading ADT plugin. Try to reinstall. If error continues, avoid direct install by typing the site. Download ADT bundle and install it  in Eclipse,

> Help-> Install new software-> Add-> Archive.

Aftre that, tell your SDK Location to Eclipse as,

> Window-> Preferences-> Android-> SDK Location

Answer (score 0):

Well, could you give us your log file so we can see what is the problem :) ?
Could you give us more details about your installation ? What platform are you running on ? Linux, Mac, Windows ? If Linux, are you using the package provided by your distribution, or the one from the web
(Sorry to the moderator but I don't have enough reputation to comment directly)

Without the log file, I could think of Eclipse not finding the path of your ADT installation, check that your PATH includes the executable.
Check that you have Java JDK installed too.
If you're developping with Linux, and it's a 64bit installation, check you have your 32bit librairies installed (IA32)

```
 apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Comment: i'm using windows ultimate 64-bit, i have installed jdk too.. i couldn't update my log file.. it was too large